# How to add content-type to WordPress favicon

Tags: php, wordpress

Good afternoon, there is a standard favicon output -

```
<link rel="icon" href="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/MyLogo.png" sizes="32x32" />
```

Is there an example function and hook that would add type=" desired type" to the output in the link

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically change this through functions.php

```
function myfavicon() {
    $path = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . "/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/MyLogo.png";  
    echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="' . $path . '" sizes="32x32" />';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'myfavicon');
```

I also have added the absolute path because for IE you need a fully qualified URL instead of a relative url.